# Sdk módulo r503 fingerprint

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi, sdk

Hola estoy diseñando un sistema de ingreso de personas con el módulo r503 fingerprint, módulo que Lee la huella digital de forma capacitiva, lleva un memoria dónde almacena las huellas y verifica, mi intención es almacenar en una base de datos las huellas, hay librerías en arduino,python, he usado las librerías pero no obtengo la huella digital para almacenar en la base de datos, en python obtengo las huellas, esa información de huella cambia si cambio la posición del mismo dedo y es un poco complicado, obtuve el link de sdk

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pznvlzx8qx5nfr3/AABpzhSyjqH0qWNYgMvxqAA9a?dl=0

En el apartado finger Reader sdk

Mi intención es usarlo con raspberry pi 4 con python, tengo conocimientos basicos de python, he intentando con chatgpt usando "ctypes" y seleccionando el dll pero me sale error,
Como uso el sdk en python? para obtener las huellas digitales procesadas
Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Puedes ser más claro respecto a la pregunta? También incluye el código de lo que intentaste. Mira cómo crear un [example] para que podamos responderte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

hola gracias por tu tiempo, como se debe trabajar con dll en python ?
estoy utilizando python de 32

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pznvlzx8qx5nfr3/AABpzhSyjqH0qWNYgMvxqAA9a?dl=0&file_subpath=%2Ffingerprint+reader+SDK%2FAPEx_DLL+Function+Manual+V3.03.pdf&preview=fingerprint+reader+SDK.rar

```
`import ctypes

# Carga la DLL
my_dll = ctypes.PyDLL('D:/fingerprint/pyfingerprint-abril/SynoAPIEx.dll')  # Reemplaza con la ruta de tu DLL

# Utiliza funciones de la DLL
resultado = my_dll.PSOpenDeviceEx(0xEF01,0xFFFFFFFF,5,57600,10,0)  # Reemplaza con el nombre de la función de la DLL que deseas llamar

# Puedes usar el resultado en tu código de Python como sea necesario
print("El resultado es:", resultado)`
```

Comment: Disculpa, esto no es un foro. Esta publicación debería ser una respuesta pero no parece responder tu pregunta. Corrígeme si me equivoco. Tu pregunta ya tiene votos negativos, no querrás conseguir más. Podrías perder el privilegio de preguntar y responder. Te invito a mirar [ask] y [answer] y resolver demás dudas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio en el [help] para mejorar tus publicaciones.

Comment: Si querías responder a mí comentario deberias haberlo hecho mediante otro comentario. Si querías asegurarte de notificarme, arroba mí nombre como en Twitter (`@Mateo`).